# Menu dropdown in position relative does not shift other items down

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to render items in a row, for each there is a custom dropdown menu. I have set the menu to `position: relative` because it has to be close to its respective item. However, with many items in a row when I open the menu, it shift everything else down. I tried setting position to absolute, but that simply makes the menu float to the bottom of the page. How do I open the menu for each of the items without shifting all the other content down?

Below is the codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-bohr-fmvh4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Set ```position: relative``` to the ```Chip``` component and ```position: absolute``` to ```ul``` tag.

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-edison-hfvu6?file=/src/Pill.js

Comment: thank you @vivek, but it doesn't work exactly with a scroll, if there is a lot of data and I scroll the page, the menu stays in one place on the page. Is there a way to have it be dynamic to the location of the item?